# Adapter RecyclerView

Tags: android

Помогите с Adapter'ом для чата.

Сейчас Apadter выглядит вот так:

```
public class MSGAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MSGAdapter.MSGViewHolder> {

ArrayList<MessageModel> messages;

public MSGAdapter(ArrayList<MessageModel> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
}

@Override
public MSGViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.msg_card_layout, parent, false);
    MSGAdapter.MSGViewHolder nh = new MSGAdapter.MSGViewHolder(v);
    return nh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MSGViewHolder holder, int position) {
       Context ctx = holder.itemView.getContext();
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparamsFile = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
        holder.message_.setText(messages.get(position).getContent().toString()); // Добавление текста сообщения
        if(messages.get(position).getFile() != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.get(position).getFile().size(); i++) {
                ImageView file = new ImageView(ctx);//Изображение вложения
                file.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                file.setLayoutParams(lparamsFile);
                switch (messages.get(position).getFile().get(i).getType().toString()) {
                    case "img":
                        Glide.with(ctx).load(messages.get(position).getFile().get(i).getSrc()).into(file);
                        break;
                    case "doc":
                        file.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.doc));
                        break;
                    case "audio":
                        file.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.audio));
                        break;
                    case "video":
                        file.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.video));
                        break;
                }

                holder.fileLayout.addView(file);
            }
        }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messages.size();
}

public static class MSGViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    CardView cv;
    LinearLayout mainLayout, messageLayout, fileLayout;
    TextView message_;
    public MSGViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.msg_card);

        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        messageLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_layout);
        fileLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_layout);
        message_ = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
}
```

Сообщения(и вложения) отображаются нормально вот только во время скролинга списка сообщений, вложения ведут себя "хаотично".

Я уже понял что это происходит из-за того что я объявляю вложения сообщений(**ImageView**) в `OnBindViewHolder`, как мне его можно "перенести" на этап OnCreateViewHolder если мне заранее неизвестно сколько вложений будет в сообщении? 
Мне их(вложения) нужно получать из массива (`messages.get(position).getFile()`)во время отправки сообщений

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435529/recyclerview-adapter-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5?rq=1
Ответ отсюда должен помочь.

Comment: Спасибо, читал это. там вариант с созданием еще одного view holder. Я хотел бы узнать как это реализовать без дополнительного view holder'а, возможно ли это вообще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ресайклервью холдеры переиспользуются. Советую перед каждым биндом "обнулять" холдер. В Вашем случае предлагаю в поле холдера держать ссылку на ImageView и перед биндом его чистить. И текст в TextView тоже не будет лишним очищать.

```
public class MSGAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MSGAdapter.MSGViewHolder> {

ArrayList<MessageModel> messages;

public MSGAdapter(ArrayList<MessageModel> messages) {
this.messages = messages;
}

@Override
public MSGViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View v =     LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.msg_card_layout,     parent, false);
MSGAdapter.MSGViewHolder nh = new MSGAdapter.MSGViewHolder(v);
return nh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MSGViewHolder holder, int position) {
   Context ctx = holder.itemView.getContext();
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparamsFile = new      LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
   holder.clearImage();
   holder.message_.setText("");
    holder.message_.setText(messages.get(position).getContent().toString());     // Добавление текста сообщения
        if(messages.get(position).getFile() != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.get(position).getFile().size(); i++) {
            ImageView file = new ImageView(ctx);//Изображение вложения
            file.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            file.setLayoutParams(lparamsFile);
            switch     (messages.get(position).getFile().get(i).getType().toString()) {
                case "img":
                    Glide.with(ctx).load(messages.get(position).getFile().get(i).getSrc()).into(file);
                    break;
                case "doc":
                    file.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.doc));
                    break;
                case "audio":
                    file.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.audio));
                    break;
                case "video":
                    file.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.video));
                    break;
            }

            holder.addImage(file);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return messages.size();
}

public static class MSGViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements     View.OnClickListener{
ImageView file;
CardView cv;
LinearLayout mainLayout, messageLayout, fileLayout;
TextView message_;
public MSGViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.msg_card);

    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    messageLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_layout);
    fileLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_layout);
    message_ = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
}

public void addImage(ImageView file){
    this.file = file;
    fileLayout.addView(file);
}
public void clearImage(){
    if (file!=null){
        fileLayout.removeView(file);
        file = null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Помогло, только там вместе fileManager нужно было поставить fileLayout

Comment: да, опечатка. поправил.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MSGViewHolder holder, int position) {
       Context ctx = holder.itemView.getContext();
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparamsFile = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
        holder.message_.setText(messages.get(position).getContent().toString()); // Добавление текста сообщения
        holder.message_.setTag(position);
        if(messages.get(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.message_.getTag()))).getFile() != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.get(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.message_.getTag()))).getFile().size(); i++) {
                ImageView file = new ImageView(ctx);//Изображение вложения
                file.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                file.setLayoutParams(lparamsFile);
                switch (messages.get(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.message_.getTag()))).getFile().get(i).getType().toString()) {
                    case "img":
                        Glide.with(ctx).load(messages.get(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.message_.getTag()))).getFile().get(i).getSrc()).into(file);
                        break;
                    case "doc":
                        file.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.doc));
                        break;
                    case "audio":
                        file.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.audio));
                        break;
                    case "video":
                        file.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.video));
                        break;
                }

                holder.fileLayout.addView(file);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Не помогло, вложения сообщений дублируются, после отравки 2го сообщения с вложением в 1м сообщении вложение дублируется, при отправки 3го сообщения во 2м сообщении создается еще одна но уже во втором

Answer (score 0):

В случае, если нет вложения imageview не меняется. И получаются случаи, когда грузится старый. Нужно что-то сделать, когда его нету)

Comment: imageView не меняется уже(в случае которой описан ниже), он просто повторяется чтобы я не отправил предыдущие сообщения дублируют свои вложение